# Cannot remove spacing between controls in TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, tablelayoutpanel

There's some spacing between the Buttons I add to my `TableLayoutPanel`. I removed the border in the Button and set the Margin and Padding to 0 in the Panel. But I continue getting that spacing.

tableLayoutPanel.RowCount is set to 8 and the `Rows` collection I've added 8 rows with `Size Type Absolute`.

Am I missing something? Here's the code:

```
    private void FillSelectLayout()
    {
        tableLayoutPanelSelect.Controls.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanelSelect.RowStyles.Clear();

        tableLayoutPanelSelect.RowCount = 8;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Button buttonSelector = new Button();
            buttonSelector.Height = 64;
            buttonSelector.Width = 100;
            buttonSelector.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            buttonSelector.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            buttonSelector.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            tableLayoutPanelSelect.Controls.Add(buttonSelector, 0, i);
        }
    }
```

Here's how it's displayed:

[image]

Comment: I don't see where you set up the TLP, RowSizes, Margin, Padding..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove the space between buttons in cells, it's enough to set dock property of them to fill and then remove default margins of buttons:

```
var b = new Button();
b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
b.Margin = new Padding(0);
```

**Note:**

- Usually it's better to set `Dock` property of controls which you host in cells to `Fill`. This way your controls will follow [`TableLayouPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview?WT.mc_id=5003235) sizing rules which you set for columns and rows.
- [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview?WT.mc_id=5003235) use `Margin` property of control to set the location of control in cell. So If you don'n want to set `Dock` and you prefer to set the `Size` manually, it's enough to set the `Margin` only.

Comment: I did not need to set the `Dock` property but `Margin` zero is the key.

Comment: @Crowcoder Usually it's better to set `Dock` property of controls which you host in cells to `Fill`. This way your controls will follow `TableLayouPanel` sizing rules which you set for columns and rows.

Comment: I had tried setting both margins to 0 and dock styles to fill as advised to no avail. I'm still seeing the gap

Answer (score 2):

*I .. set the Margin and Padding to 0 in the Panel.*

Why didn't you remove the `Margin` in the `Buttons` instead:

```
buttonSelector.Margin = new Padding(0);
```

[MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229627(v=vs.100).aspx)

> The Margin property defines the space around the control that keeps
>   other controls a specified distance from the control's borders.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while using different control in `TableLayoutPanel`

You can do this

1. Go to Design View
2. Click on the properties
3. GoTo Columns, When you click text box besides Columns, a button (...) appears on extreme right, click it
4. A pop up window appears, Select AutoSize (Instead of Absolute or Percentage).
5. In the same window in `Show:` select `Rows` and again select Autosize.
6. Click okay and you are done.